# How to create a html form in rst file?

Tags: html, gitlab, restructuredtext, forge

I want to display a form which contains button, check box, dropdown etc... using rst.
This form will be displayed in forge tool where in users will fill the form and submit. When user submits the form, a mail will be opened to send the details to some mail box id.

I tried with below directive in rst

```
.. code-block:: html

 <html>
  <body>
   Test 
  </body>
 </html>
```

I added the above code snippet in rst file and committed in gitlab. When I view in gitlab (display rendered file option), the html element is not displayed.

Could you help me to find a way to display the html elements using rst?

Comment: You can't do that with RST. This is a simple markup language not intended for any logic, including forms. You should consider creating form in plain html instead.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. You must indent the HTML at least two spaces. That said, the form needs to either send an HTTP post request to some server or just use `<a href="mailto:user@host.com?subject=subject&body=body">send mail</a>`.